# Java 8 CompletableFuture - how to run multiple functions on same input

Tags: java, java-8, completable-future

I've the following working piece of code using `CompleteableFuture`:

```
CompletableFuture<SomeObject> future = CompletableFuture.
            supplyAsync( () -> f1() ).
            thenApplyAsync( f1Output -> f2( f1Output ) ).
            thenApplyAsync( f2Output -> f3( f2Output ) );
```

Is it possible to run another future that receives `f1Output` as an `input?` Something like:

```
CompletableFuture<SomeObject> future = CompletableFuture.
            supplyAsync( () -> f1() ).
            thenApplyAsync( f1Output -> f2( f1Output ) ).
            someApiThatRuns( f1Output -> f4( f1Output ) ). // <-- 
            thenApplyAsync( f2Output -> f3( f2Output ) );
```

If this simplifies things one can ignore the result returned by `f4()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't mind running `f2` and `f4` in sequence, the simplest is just to call both in your lambda:

```
CompletableFuture<SomeObject> future = CompletableFuture.
            supplyAsync(() -> f1() ).
            thenApplyAsync(f1Output -> { f4(f1Output); return f2(f1Output); } ).
            thenApplyAsync(f2Output -> f3(f2Output));
```

If however you want to run `f2` and `f4` in parallel, you can just store the intermediate future in a variable:

```
CompletableFuture<SomeObject> f1Future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> f1());

CompletableFuture<SomeObject> future = f1Future.
            thenApplyAsync(f1Output -> f2(f1Output)).
            thenApplyAsync(f2Output -> f3(f2Output));

f1Future.thenAcceptAsync(f1Output -> f4(f1Output));
```

Comment: For me solution #2 is better, thanks! Can you explain how f1Output is still accessible in the second statement, if it was "declared" in the first one? In addition, is there no API that can achieve the same behavior so we end with just one line?

Comment: @Seffy `f1Output` is just a name. You can call the lambda parameter of the second statement `ulnsvnosuvcnr`, if you wish, and it would still contain a reference to the object of `f1Future`’s completion. Besides that, when you chain actions, you are forming *dependencies*. When these two actions are independent, you should not define a wrong dependency, just to follow the irrational wish to “end with just one line” (especially as that “one line” still spans multiple lines when using reasonable formatting).